# Javascript parsing Times without Date

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I need to parse and manipulate Times without Dates in my code. For example i might get the string "15:00" from a timepicker. I want to turn this into a Time object of some kind - I normally work in Python which has distinct Date, Time, and Datetime objects.

However all the solutions i've seen focus on using the Date object. This cannot parse a string like "15:00" since it requires day information. I don't want to add arbitrary Date information to Times - especially since Date appears to make assumptions about things like daylight saving depending on the day and the locale, and there appears to be a risk of it automatically attempting to translate the time into a given locale. Furthermore I want to be able to add times, e.g. "15:00 + 1 hour"

What is the recommended solution to parse and handle "raw" times not associated to dates?

Comment: If you don't want to write your own code to do it, there's [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) or [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com).

Comment: I'd recommend writing the few lines you need for that yourself. As there's no calendar concern, it's simple.

Comment: That's what i was hoping to avoid. Moment.js and Date.js both focus on DateTimes, not Times, so you still have to glue arbitrary Date information to a Time before you can use it. I can imagine it's not fundamentally complicated to implement, but I'm surprised this doesn't exist already.

Comment: date includes time ya know, so just work on 1/1/1970 and throw out the scraps when you're done. It's not like all that extra data info will slow down the time manipulation...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not a great solution.  JavaScript only has a `Date` object, which is probably misnamed since it is really a date+time.

One thing you might want to think about deeper - you say you want to work with only time, but do you mean a *time-of-day* or do you mean a *duration of time*?  These are two related, but slightly different concepts.

For example, you said you might want an operation like "15:00 + 1 hour".  Well that would clearly be 16:00 either way.  But what about "15:00 + 10 hours"?  It would be 25:00 if you are talking about a duration, but it might be 01:00 if you are talking about time-of-day.

Actually, it might *not* be 01:00, since not all days have 24 hours in them.  Some days have 23, 23.5, 24.5, or 25 hours, depending on what time zone and whether DST is starting or stopping on that day.  So in the time-of-day context, you probably *do* want to include a particular date and zone in your calculation.  Of course, if you are talking about straight 24-hours days, then this point is irrelevant.

If you are talking about *durations* - you might want to look again at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), but not at the `moment` object. There is another object there, `moment.duration`.  The reference is [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/).

And finally, you might want to consider just using plain javascript to parse out hours and minutes from the time string as numbers.  Manipulate the numbers as necessary, and then output a string again.  But your question seems like you're looking for something more managed.

Comment: Unfortunately I am looking for "Time of Day" rather than duration (so moment.js is out). It looks like there is no managed solution and i have to use regex string parsing - which is a shame because that's the kind of fiddly stuff prone to subtle bugs that i prefer to have handled by a well tested library.

Comment: If you can place that time on a particular day, then `Date` or `moment` would still be a good idea.  If it's always detached (like the hours a restaurant is open on each day of the week) the edge cases are much more challenging.  I don't know of any good js library for this.  sorry.

Comment: Any change on this?  I need a totally detached Time (hours and minutes) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 89):

Here's a moment.js solution for 12 or 24 hour times:

```
moment('7:00 am', ['h:m a', 'H:m']); // Wed Dec 30 2015 07:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
moment('17:00', ['h:m a', 'H:m']);   // Wed Dec 30 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
moment('17:00 am', ['h:m a', 'H:m']);// Wed Dec 30 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
moment('17:00 pm', ['h:m a', 'H:m']);// Wed Dec 30 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/

Comment: i have been looking for this all day

Comment: Wow... this is exactly it! Basically the date of the Time of Day doesn't matter for my (and possibly OP's) use case. Just needed to convert a time string into a valid momentjs object. And to think all other posts around the web spoke of such "unfortunateness" and "impossible" hehe. Thank you!!

Comment: @SunLee "impossible" is just another job :-)

Comment: This can stab you in the back on daylight saving time.

Comment: That is a very dramatic day of programming.

Answer (score 21):

I ended up using the following since I was already using `moment` in my app:

```
var str = '15:16:33';
var d = new moment(str, 'HH:mm:ss');
```

See [Moment String+Format docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) for other format strings you can use.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this recently for a project but didnt really need to include moment.js, the method I used was to manually parse the time like this:

```
function parseTime(time) {    
    let timeInt = parseInt(time);
    let minutes = time.substring(3,5);

    // you could then add or subtract time here as needed

    if(time > '12:00') {
         return `${timeInt - 12}:${minutes} PM`;
    } else {
         return `${timeInt}:${minutes} AM`;
    }
}
```

Use this as an alternative starter if you don't want to use moment. Note this example uses es6 syntax.

Answer (score 3):

And I know I am over 8 years late to this party, but it is worth noting that `moment.js` is no longer being developed and is on a pacemaker for maintenance.  They actually do NOT recommend using moment.js for new apps.

More details are found here: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I know I'm way late to the party. Like 6 years late but this was something I needed to figure out and have it formatted HH:mm:ss (24 hours).

```
moment().format(moment.HTML5_FMT.TIME_SECONDS); // 17:44:56
```

You can also pass in a parameter like, `2019-11-08T17:44:56.144`.

```
moment('2019-11-08T17:44:56.144').format(moment.HTML5_FMT.TIME_SECONDS); // 17:44:56
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/

Answer (score 1):

We know that the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) class in `JavaScript` must always contain a `date`, and entering `time` alone is not enough.

But when asked, I do not need to enter a date. This could mean:

- You intend to compare two dates with each other.
- The two dates are shared on the same day.

If so, then as a trick, you can add a specific date(any date) to your time as string. (E.g. `0000-01-01` )

For example, this code is incorrect:

```js
var d1 = '00:53:57.123';
var d2 = '00:53:58.124';
console.log(new Date(d2).getTime() - new Date(d1).getTime());
//result: NaN
```

But this way you can get the right result:

```js
var d1 = '00:53:57.123';
var d2 = '00:53:58.124';
d1 = '0000-01-01 ' + d1;
d2 = '0000-01-01 ' + d2;
console.log(new Date(d2).getTime() - new Date(d1).getTime());
//result: 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am writing this 8 years later but it's no longer advisable to use the moment.js library nowadays since it's no longer supported, luxo.js is the preferred(like the evolution of moments.js) one you can find more here: https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html