# Converting a time string to a time value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like "01:12:33" which is HH:MM:SS format. How can I convert that to a time value in JS?

I've tried the new Date() constructor and setting the year and day values to 0, then doing getTime(), but I am not having any lucky.

Comment: You want a date object, or a unix timestamp?

Comment: date object, something that looks like HH:MM:SS preferably

Comment: Unfortunately, JS does not have a class to represent a date without time. See this other post for viable alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884586/javascript-parsing-times-without-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript parsing Times without Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884586/javascript-parsing-times-without-date)

Answer (score 28):

Prefix it with a date:

```
var hms = "01:12:33";
var target = new Date("1970-01-01T" + hms);
console.log(target);
```

There `target.getTime()` will give you the number of milliseconds since the start of the day;

Or, if you need it to be today's date:

```
var now = new Date();
var nowDateTime = now.toISOString();
var nowDate = nowDateTime.split('T')[0];
var hms = '01:12:33';
var target = new Date(nowDate + 'T' + hms);
console.log(target);
```

There `target.getTime()` will give you the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: for todays date I needed to add a space after nowDate to correctly format  

var target = new Date(nowDate + " " + hms);

Comment: "1970-01-01 01:12:33" is not a format supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari at least returns an invalid date.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the following function that does the job for you :

```
function getDateFromHours(time) {
    time = time.split(':');
    let now = new Date();
    return new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), ...time);
}
console.log(getDateFromHours('01:12:33'));
```

Comment: Why the second Date? `now.setHours(time[0], time[1], 0, 0)` is simpler. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To be able to do this, there should be a conversion of the string in HH:MM:SS format to JavaScript time.

Firstly, we can use Regular Expression (RegEx) to properly extract the values in that string.

```
let timeString = "01:12:33";
```

Extract values with RegEx

```
let regExTime = /([0-9]?[0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])/;
let regExTimeArr = regExTime.exec(timeString); // ["01:12:33", "01", "12", "33", index: 0, input: "01:12:33", groups: undefined]
```

Convert HH, MM and SS to milliseconds

```
let timeHr = regExTimeArr[1] * 3600 * 1000;
let timeMin = regExTimeArr[2] * 60 * 1000;
let timeSec = regExTimeArr[3] * 1000;

let timeMs = timeHr + timeMin + timeSec; //4353000 -- this is the time in milliseconds.
```

In relation to another point in time, a reference time has to be given.

For instance,

```
let refTimeMs = 1577833200000  //Wed, 1st January 2020, 00:00:00;
```

The value above is is the number of milliseconds that has elapsed since the epoch time (Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00)

```
let time = new Date (refTimeMs + timeMs); //Wed Jan 01 2020 01:12:33 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)
```

Comment: Good job! Could you explain the question mark in between bracket?

Comment: It means the entity before it (to the left) could be present or not. That is, 1 or 0 instance of that entity.

Important if you want your hours to read single digits without a leading '0'. That is, '1', instead of '01'.

Comment: why does it add one hour?