# Number of hours between two strings in Javascript

Tags: reactjs, string, date

I have 2 strings "18:13:10" and "15:45:11" , I need to compute the number of hours between them ? For example a result of 6 hours and 17 minutes.

I'am working with reactjs.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of [Converting a time string to a time value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46591254/215552) and [How to get the hours difference between two date objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19225414/215552)

Comment: How is there "6 hours and 17 minutes" between 18:13:10 and 15:45:11?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript return number of days,hours,minutes,seconds between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903897/javascript-return-number-of-days-hours-minutes-seconds-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create two instances of Date object prepending a date to the full time string.
Use getTime and calculate the time difference.
Then use getHours getMinutes and getSeconds methods on Date difference.

```js
 const d1 = new Date('1970-01-01 ' + "18:13:10");
 const d2 = new Date('1970-01-01 ' + '10:01:01');

 var difference = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();

 console.log(new Date(difference).getHours()-1 + ' ' + new Date(difference).getMinutes()+ ' ' + new Date(difference).getSeconds())
```

Comment: Questions which explain code are downvoted less often that just a dump of code, especially when that code uses different values than the OP.

Comment: Oh really? Just edit my answer btw. Added some explanation to my dump of code.

Answer (score 1):

Let `Date()` do the heavy lifting for you:

```js
    const d1 = new Date('1970-01-01T' + "18:13:10" + 'Z');
    const d2 = new Date('1970-01-01T' + '15:45:11' + 'Z');
    const diff = d1 - d2; // 887900
```

The time difference is in milliseconds. To get hours and minutes and seconds:

```js
    const hours = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60*60)); // 2
    const mins = Math.floor((diff-(hours*1000*60*60)) / (1000*60)); // 27
    const secs = Math.floor(
      (diff-(hours*1000*60*60)-(mins*1000*60)) / 1000); // 59
```

Comment: I tried to change 887900 ms to hours using this : https://www.timecalculator.net/milliseconds-to-hours and the result is 0.24 hours

Comment: You need to have the next day in `d2`.

Comment: @xgeek95 `const hours = Math.floor(ms/(1000*60*60))` and `const minutes = Math.floor(ms/(1000*60))`

Comment: @HereticMonkey Why use a different day for d2? The question does not specifiy a different day.

Comment: Well, the expected outcome, "6 hours and 17 minutes" does not appear to square with the difference between 15:45 and 18:13 if they are on the same day (that would be 2 hours and 27 minutes). But it doesn't square going the other way either, so who knows?

Comment: @terrymorse how can I add number of seconds ?

Comment: @xgeek95 - I'll add seconds to the answer above.