# Converting a string (150000) to time ( hh:mm:ss) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS. Can anybody tell me whether is it possible to convert a string ( eg: "140000") to time (eg: 14:00:00) in Javascript.

Comment: `"140000".replace(/(..)(?!$)/g, '$1:')`

Comment: `'140000'.match(/../g).join(':')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit tricky, because well... there is no `Time` object in Javascript.

There is only a `Date` object, although the name is kind of misleading, because the `Date` object contains both "Date" and "Time". There is a reason behind this seemingly confusing convention. I'm not going to go into too long of a detail, but to put it shortly, referencing "Time" is unreliable (to human brain).

For that, I'll just recommend [reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884586/javascript-parsing-times-without-date) which explains it quite brilliantly.

---

Either way, this simple function will do the trick.

### `toDate(what){}`

> Upon sucessful string of time conversion, `return` a newly created `Date` object. Otherwise `return -1`. *(or you could throw an `Exception` instead, up to you really)*

```js
var str = '143025';

function toDate(what){ // turns string into Date() object
  var result;
  if (what.length === 6) { // must be in HH:MM:SS length
    var timearr = what.match(/.{1,2}/g); // splits time to HH:MM:SS array
     if (timearr[0] <= 24 && timearr[1] <= 60 && timearr[2] <= 60){
       return new Date('01 January 0001 ' + timearr[0] + ':'+
                           timearr[1] + ':' + timearr[2] + ' GMT'); // valid time format
     } 
  }
  
  return -1;
}


var mytime = toDate(str);
console.log(mytime.toUTCString());
```

Note, `Date` by itself is only expression of serialized numbers, if you want to return the time as result, you need to use the `.toString` or `.toUTCString` method from the `Date.prototype` object.

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

1. Split your text into an array using the `split` method.
2. Map over your array and replace every item that has the index can be divided by to with the `item + :` using the `map` method.
3. Join your array to be string again using the `join` method.
4. Remove the last `:` from your result.

```js
let convertToTime = str => str
            .split("")
            .map((item, index) => (index % 2 != 0) ? item + ':' : item)
            .join("")
            .slice(0, -1);
console.log(convertToTime("140000")); // 14:00:00
console.log(convertToTime("173003")); // 17:30:03
console.log(convertToTime("225510")); // 22:55:10
console.log(convertToTime("010201")); // 01:02:01
```